# Fallo en una copia .bat

Tags: batch

Estoy tratado de hacer una copia de seguridad con un archivo bat pero al copiar la segunda carpeta el proceso se detiene y no se completa correctamente. Debo decir que la segunda carpeta es más grande y contiene unos 30GB de tamaño. ¿Por qué podría estar fallando la copia? ¿Debo añadir algun parámetro adicional o cambiar algún comando?. 
Aqui va el código que estoy guardando como backup.bat:

```
Set mes=%DATE:~3,2%
Set dia=%DATE:~0,2%
Set anio=%DATE:~6,4%

rem Carpeta donde copiar todos los archivos:
set carpetaFinal=MIPC_%anio%_%mes%_%dia%\
set carpeta=C:\Windows\Fonts

rem CREAR PRIMERA CARPETA Y COPIAR
set carpeta1=Fonts
xcopy "%carpeta%\*.*" "%carpetaFinal%\%carpeta1%\" /s/y/f

set carpeta=E:\MISARCHIVOS
rem CREAR SEGUNDA CARPETA Y COPIAR
set carpeta2=MISARCHIVOS
xcopy "%carpeta%\*.*" "%carpetaFinal%\%carpeta2%\" /s/y/f
```

Comment: Cuando trata de realizar la copia y se detiene,  ¿se muestra algún mensaje?

Comment: No, ningún mensaje. He comprobado ya varias veces y se detiene en un archivo .zip con nombre algo largo. Después se cierra la consola sin mostrar ningún mensaje. Espero que esto pueda ser de ayuda.

Comment: He actualizado el código siguiendo tu anterior mensaje con:
set carpetaFinal=G:\MIPC_%anio%_%mes%_%dia%\
pero sigue fallando de la misma manera que expliqué anteriormente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo usaría mejor el comando ROBOCOPY ya que al contrario que XCOPY, este si copia atributos relacionados con los permisos, seguridad y propietarios.

```
ROBOCOPY "%carpeta%\*.*" "%carpetaFinal%\%carpeta2%\" /FP /V /ZB /E /MIR /XO
```

Añadiría también una secuencia de errores con

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 
ECHO "Éxito"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
ECHO "Fallo copia"

Comment: ¿esta bien escrito? ahora ni siquiera copia la primera carpeta.

Comment: Set mes=%DATE:~3,2%
Set dia=%DATE:~0,2%
Set anio=%DATE:~6,4%

rem Carpeta donde copiar todos los archivos:
set carpetaFinal=G:\MIPC_%anio%_%mes%_%dia%\

set carpeta=C:\Windows\Fonts
rem CREAR PRIMERA CARPETA Y COPIAR
set carpeta1=Fonts
ROBOCOPY "%carpeta%\*.*" "%carpetaFinal%\%carpeta1%\" /FP /V /ZB /E /MIR /XO

set carpeta=E:\MISARCHIVOS
rem CREAR SEGUNDA CARPETA Y COPIAR
set carpeta2=MISARCHIVOS
ROBOCOPY "%carpeta%\*.*" "%carpetaFinal%\%carpeta2%\" /FP /V /ZB /E /MIR /XO
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO "Éxito" IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO "Fallo copia"

Comment: ... y tampoco muestra error. Se cierra sin siquiera comenzar.

Comment: Ok, veo que funciona tu código pero con estos cambios:
ROBOCOPY %carpeta%\ %carpetaFinal%\%carpeta2%\  /MIR
La sintaxis es distinta que en XCOPY. Tampoco puse /FP /V /ZB /E /XO puesto que con /MIR era suficiente. Gracias por tu colaboración!

Comment: Me alegro de que te sirviera!!